# Encontrar .keystore do APK

Tags: android, keystore

Alguém sabe onde eu encontro o arquivo .keystore do meu APK assinado digitalmente?

É o mesmo .jks?

Comment: Sim, é o .jks. xD

Comment: Ah! Legal! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O JKS(Java KeyStore) você não consegue encontra-lo se ainda não criou. Antigamente a extensão do certificado era `.keystore` aí depois de um tempo o Google mudou para `.jks`. Para criar veja o comando abaixo como exemplo:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-key.jks -alias alias_name -keyalg 
RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Veja aqui [neste artigo mais detalhes de como gerar certificado release/debug](https://coderwall.com/p/r09hoq/android-generate-release-debug-keystores).

> É o mesmo .jks?

Sim é o mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado pela informação

Comment: @adventistaam precisar, estamos por aqui.

Comment: ele cria para qual pasta?

Comment: @adventistaam você que escolhe a pasta onde deve ser criada. Se você inserir o comando sem definir o local, ele será criado na pasta raiz onde você abriu o cmd caso seja windows.

Comment: no caso eu segui esse comando no linux

Comment: @adventistaam verifique em seu terminal qual é a pasta raiz quando você abre ele. O arquivo estará lá. Para direcionar pra uma pasta específica, na hora de colocar o comando keytool, faça desta forma: /home/my-key.jks Ai vai salvar na sua home